# "She DIDN'T enjoy it" or "She NOT enjoyed it"?

Tags: past-tense, negation

I have confusion about the following sentence.

> 1. Sue enjoys her work. She wouldn't do it if she **not** enjoyed it.
> 2. Sue enjoys her work. She wouldn't do it if she **didn't** enjoy it.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English, there are two rules for how to state the negative of a verb.

1. "Not" comes after the verb.

   > Correct: "I **am not** at home."
   >
   > Incorrect: "I **not am** at home."
2. Except for a few cases, you must rephrase to use the auxiliary verb "do".

   > Correct: "She **does not eat** meat." (from "She eats meat" -> "She does eat meat")
   >
   > Incorrect: "She **eats not** meat."

"She not enjoyed it" is wrong on both of these rules. "She did not enjoy it" (shortened to "She didn't enjoy it") is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no' here? The sentences there seem wrong to me, grammatically.

Comment: You are right that the sentences after "No:" are wrong, grammatically. Lines beginning with "Yes:" give examples of correct usage. Lines beginning with "No:" give examples of incorrect usage.

Comment: I've edited your post.

Comment: The main exceptions where not to use *do* with negative verbs is A) if the verb is *to be*.  In this case *not* comes after the verb - "I am not surprised; they're not here, etc." and B) if *have* or *not* is already there as an auxiliary verb, you put *not* in front of the second word of the verb (no need to add an add an auxiliary if one is there already, basically)  - "I have gone to the park, I have not gone to the park; They were working yesterday, They were not working yesterday; She had been going to the doctor, She had not been going to the doctor."

Comment: @LawrenceC: I think you mean "*have* or *be*", rather than "*have* or *not*". Also, (B) applies to auxiliary verbs in general ("I could, I could not").

Answer (score 2):

Sue enjoys her work. She wouldn't do it if she not enjoyed it. - Sounds grammatically incorrect

Sue enjoys her work. She wouldn't do it if she didn't enjoy it. - This one is correct.

More examples

I like my job. I wouldn't have done it for four years if i had not liked it.
I like my job. I wouldn't do it if i didn't like it.

And FYI - your title of the question contains grammatical error.

It should be - Is this a correct sentence ? OR
Is it a correct sentence ? OR
Which one of the following is the correct sentence ?

Comment: The judgments given in the beginning of this answer are correct, but the purpose of ELL isn't to provide proofreading services ("This is right, this isn't").  Instead, we'd like to explain *why* the sentences are grammatical or ungrammatical so the OP (and others) can learn and form grammatical sentences themselves in the future.

Comment: @snailboat : off the topic, I want to make comunity about proofreading in here. So what am I do for that?